# compare and highlight difference of two strings containing html in php

Tags: php, highlighting, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two string in PHP which both contain HTML. (they are both placed into a database via a wysiwyg editor).

The result I want to get is to see which words are removed and which ones have been added.

To do this I'm using [this bit of code](http://pastebin.com/dU45FKNL) as follows:

```
$old = "<p>Lorem ipsum is standard dummy text</p>";
$new = "<p>Lorem ipsum was standard dummy jibbrish</p>";
echo htmlDiff($old, $new);
```

which works perfectly fine. However when I add some tags such as `<li>`, the fun ends.

For example if I would have the following:

```
$old = "<p>Lorem ipsum is standard dummy text. <ul><li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum</li><li>Dolor</li></ul></p>";

$new = "<p>Lorem ipsum was standard dummy jibbrish. <ul><li>Lorem</li><li>Dolor</li></ul></p>";

echo htmlDiff($old, $new);
```

The `<del>` tag gets added correctly after the first list item, but the removed list item gets placed outside of the `<del>` tag, making it look like it was not removed.

I could resolve this by stripping all tags, but I would like to keep the layout of both strings.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try one of the following alternatives to the htmlDiff function:

1. [PHP inline dif](http://web.archive.org/web/20080506155528/http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/) mini-library which produces results [like this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080419063437/http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/diff_example_0.2.html)
2. [Horde_Text_Diff](http://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Text_Diff/download) library
3. [xdiff_string_diff](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) function from xdiff extension